# Displaying the wrong launch image on my app. Tried to replace it in several ways

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem with my app´s launch image. Early on in the development I added a sample image as launch image. Now when the app is ready for release, I can’t change the launch image.

I have tried changing it inside xcode in the project summary, deleting the files from the project file and replacing the files with the new image with the correct name. No luck. It still displays wrong on all devices.

I don’t even have the image in the project anymore.

Is there anyone in here who knows what’s wrong, or have experienced anything like this?

The launch image is for iPhone and iPad, portrait.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go back to before you tried to replace the image. Replace the image file with your new one.

Ah, but that didn't work, right? Here's the catch:

1. Clean your build folder. The build process may not always pick up your new launch image. (Hold down Option when looking at the Product menu, or delete the contents of **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**.)
2. Delete the app from the simulator and/or phone. The application installer will usually not copy the new image over.

(These steps are not always both necessary, but since they must be performed in this order if they're both needed, I just do them both as listed.)

Here's why:

1. When you build, Xcode copies the various files that are part of your product to DerivedData. This may not always copy changed files over existing files.
2. When you install to the simulator or device for debugging, this is yet another file copy which may not always copy changed files over existing files.

Note that the App Store installer on the phone does a better job of installing, and you won't get partial installs like this. However, until you can prove to yourself that your application has been built with the right image — i.e. that you're failing in #2, not #1 — I wouldn't trust this.

Comment: Aha! So if I get my app approved the new image will be there? I have tried deleting it from all my devices and rebuilding them.
Thanks a lot man! Because I really started to wonder what was going on…

Comment: There's another case I missed, which I've added to my answer. But no: My point was that the App Store installer doesn't make mistakes like this. Whatever app you submit the users will get. But until you've got the new image appearing in your own tests, I wouldn't trust that you've actually got it building with the new image.

Comment: Uhm. I tried building it on a new phone, with no luck. The old image that don’t exists anymore still appeared.you are talking about cleaning the build folder. Are you talking about the files that are in the Build Phases tab?

Comment: No, hold down option when going to the Clean command. Or delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I deleted all the files in DerivedData and woop, it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: A Clean really should do this for us. It's pretty important that a clean cleans. Still not fixed in XCode 6.3.2 :/

Comment: Yup. No argument. For what it's worth, I believe this does *not* occur if Archive is used.

Comment: Not even cleaning derived data solved this bug for me. I had to shut down my test device and relaunch it before I got the new launch image.

Comment: You saw the second step, right? It should have done the rest.

Comment: That's literally step 1.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to deleting derived data as part of the clean I found that it wasn't enough to delete the app from the test device, I also had to reboot the device.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me until I did the following steps:

- Go to project's files in xcode
- Open the Products Folder
- Right Click on your *.app product
- Choose show in finder
- Go up 3 levels up to Build Folder
- Delete this Build folder
- Build
- That's it

You may also want to try both approaches of deleting the files from

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XCode 8.2.1, lots of targets, and asset catalogs.  I could not reliably set the app icon set or launch image set for configuration of any target.

If my image sets are named globally uniquely to the workspace, I have no problem specifying the right one.

If the image sets in different catalogs have the same name, i.e. AppIcon, LaunchImage, XCode seems to pick the image set from the alphabetically first asset catalog.

So, my solution was to name each image set in every asset catalog prefixed with the asset catalog's name.  That way it's organized and globally unique.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin users, the only solution I could find to this problem was to do the following:

1. Remove the app from the device/simulator
2. Restart the device/simulator
3. Deploy and run the app

Deleting the app, cleaning the build, deleting the bin and obj directories, and rebuilding, doesn't work. The device/simulator has to be restarted for it to forget the old cached image.

As Steven Fisher points out, this wouldn't happen for a proper install from the App Store, where it 'does a better job of installing'.