# Installed a control from github - now its launch with every app - in the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I Wanted to try some controls for an animated splash screen, So I installed on my application (with cocoapods) first [CBZSplashView](https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView), removed it and then [SKSplashView](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SKSplashView)
and removed it too.

Now, no matter what App I launch (And I have like 20), it opens with the splash screen effect. It must be something with the simulator (with a real device it doesn't happen). I tried to remove the cache, removed all the simulators, but nothing.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Not sure if this is related... When I change the launch screen on my apps the change doesn't take effect immediately. Believe it gets cached. Try the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987713/displaying-the-wrong-launch-image-on-my-app-tried-to-replace-it-in-several-ways

Comment: already removed DerivedData and build folder plenty of times, didn't help, any other idea? :D

Comment: Nope, sorry! Maybe file an issue over at the GitHub pages.

Comment: Have you reset content and setting of your simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reset your simulator, in Xcode8 you can remove your simulator in 'Devices' page(press 'command + shift + 2'), try remove it and add again.

In fact the info & APP in simulator is saved in a folder(the folder routes is changed in Xcode8 that I can't write it right now), folder name equal to a random string(equal to the identifier in 'Devices' page),remove and add again means rebuild the folder.

[image]

Comment: Hey my friend, thanks, but already done that - that's what i meant when i said "removed all simulators" :)